# How to Change Target API Version in Visual Studio Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

My VS worked well before I synchronized my project with my friend's using GitHub. After that, somehow I notice Visual Studio targets different location to android.jar file. So, whenever I compile my code, I receive the following error.

> Could not find android.jar for API Level 24. This means the Android
>   SDK platform for API Level 24 is not installed. Either install it in
>   the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...), or
>   change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is
>   installed.
>   (C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK\platforms\android-24\android.jar
>   missing.)

`C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK\platforms\android-24\android.jar` is a directory location in my friend's drive.

How to change the target location of that *android.jar* file in VS 2015?

Comment: Seems like you are sync'ing files in the `obj` and `bin` directories. Remove those directories and perform a rebuild all

Answer (score 20):

Looks like your app is trying to use Android N tools to compile or targeting API level 23

Under your Android project properties -> Application, set the `Target Android Version` and `Compile using Android Version` to API Level 23 to fix it

Comment: @MichaelO.Y. the instructions in the answer are for VS. Right Click on the Android project/Select Properties/Select Application tab

Comment: Hi, I have installed Api 26 from android sdk manager but I  didn't find out Api 26 in target android version. How can I add that Api 26 as the target version of my application.

Answer (score 3):

Go to android project then right click -> Properties -> Android Manifest (scroll down) then you will see Minimun android version and Target android version.

Answer (score 1):

in vs project -> your application properties -> change target framework to your api version. that's it

Comment: possibly because it is the same answer (with less detail) as the previous answer, 3 months earlier?